# Is there an alternative to rEFIt?

Tags: dual-boot, macosx, uefi, refit

Is there an alternative to rEFIt as a bootloader where you can choose between OS X and Ubuntu? I already installed Ubuntu on my Mac with rEFIt, so if there's a better option, I can remove it now.

I'm exploring, mainly because I want one with a more appealing UI. Other improvements are still very much welcome, though.

Comment: You should also consider asking this question on [SuperUser.com](http://superuser.com). They **may** not be able to tell you how to do it using Ubuntu, but they might know more.

Answer (score 3):

It's been over two years since rEFIt has been updated, which is why I forked the [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) project from rEFIt. rEFInd includes a number of improvements, many of them related to directly booting Linux kernels with EFI stub loader support.

Comment: Just an fyi - rEFInd does not work on the latest MacBook Pro.

Comment: Given when you posted this, you probably ran into a bug in the 0.6.3 release. It's fixed in 0.6.4.

Comment: I managed to get rEFIt working. The only problem I have at this point is getting Linux to play nice with the hardware.

Comment: @RodSmith I've installed rEFInd as per the manual instructions for Mac OSX at http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#osx, but now my Mac Mini is stuck in a boot loop and the startup sound repeating over and over (the first sound is fine, but all subsequent sound distorted). What do I do now?

Comment: Also, I do not have a mac keyboard, so it doesn't recognize any boot commands.

Comment: Also, I did not use the `bless --info` command.

Comment: Try holding down the Option key at boot time; that should bring up the Mac's built-in boot manager, which should enable you to get into OS X. If the problem persists or if that doesn't work, try resetting the PRAM, as described at http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379. You can then try installing again.

Answer (score 2):

There's **elilo**

- [elilo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LILO#elilo) (the **e**fi **li**nux **lo**ader), is the EFI equivalent of LILO, a linux boot-loader like grub. This seems to be very modern and functional software, but it's not all that easy to use. There are some [installation instructions](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/workshops/linux_install/lilo.html), they're rather technical.

  Note that the rEFIt page on [Myths and Facts About Intel Macs](http://refit.sourceforge.net/myths/) says that you *won't be able to use accelerated  graphics* when using a straight EFI boot, you need to use rEFIt for that.

I think this is the only one. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: ELILO won't enable switching between Linux and OS X; ELILO is strictly a Linux boot loader, not a boot manager (except insofar as it lets you select which Linux kernel to boot).

Comment: The rEFIt documentation is very much out of date, and the claim that accelerated graphics can't be used from a direct EFI-mode boot is quite dubious. It's probably still true of some specific Mac models, but such problems have been overcome (or never existed) for many others.

Comment: @RodSmith Is it possible to install rEFInd on a CD and use it like that, instead of installing it on my OSX hard disk?

Answer (score 1):

Grub is also EFI aware.

You may find more information here:-

http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=85508

Personally I would use Grub if possible.

Considering the amount of trouble I had getting my PC to boot from GPT partitions and the lack of documentation regarding EFI/GPT and Grub/Lilo I would say you are going to have a few hours banging your head against a brick wall before you are successful. Best of luck with it.